# How to make the entire values to be selected when shift+tab is used after tab out in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs

i have an input field as amount, in which currency formatting has been done. Here i enter some values and come out using tab. Now i use shift+tab and go to the same field, so in this case i want the cursor is in the last digit i mean first number from right. Instead i want the present values to be selected by default instead of keeping cursor on the last digit.
Example: i typed `213.98` it got formatted to `$213.98` after tab out, when i again tab in here, the cursor is next to 8, instead i want `213.98` to be selected and based on arrow keys or mouse i can move to number i wish to change.
Also, when i do ctrl+Z, it has do undo all changes.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount in dolars"
            formControlName="amount" autocomplete="off" currencyInput maxDigits="9" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': eoInfo.amount.dirty  && eoInfo.amount.invalid }">
```

TS:

```
this.eoInfoForm = this.FB.group({
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

DEMO:[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyslb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcurrency-input.directive.ts)

Comment: Even if everything is selected when using shift+tab, are you going to implement the up/down arrow change yourself?

Comment: Here I meant, when we come to that input using tab key, I want the input to be selected everything, then all arrow keys and delete backspace must work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can auto select all text by adding `onClick="this.select();"` on your input.
If you want to do be able to do ctrl+z you need to add a listener for your input state like this: `(input)="update($event.target.value);"` then in the update method you can do `this.history.push(value);`. So now you should have an array called history with all different values that have been passed through.

Now to listen to ctrl+z keybind to undo a value you add `(keyup.control.z)="onKeydown($event)"` to the input and in the method you pop your history and set your new value to the the latest item in the history array. If you want you can also keep the previous value in a separate property and use that as a step in between.

I hope that this is kinda what you are looking for.

## EDIT 1:

I do have to mention I commented out the keydown event from the currency validator to show it to you.
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clp8eh)

Comment: Thanks for response, but once done with ctrlz, value goes off, when again i do ctrlz, i want the value which was there previously in edit mode

Comment: Well that's why i said to use history. I have made an example on how you can achieve this I will add it to the answer.

Comment: i did, ctrlZ so one by one value removed, what i have edited

Comment: when i do again ctrlz, then it must give me the value which was present know?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7agjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts i have forked me example here

Comment: What do you mean exactly? So If I enter 378 and I do ctrl+z it says 37 when I do it again its 3, again its empty because nothing was entered in the first place. Just like it should but I don't know what you mean with *then it must give me the value which was present*???

Comment: If you want the 378 back you can implement the reverse and use ctrl+y to redo your edits. Make a reverse array and add the values to it in reverse order.

Comment: that is correct what you said, but when i am in edit mode, i have already 378.90 for example, so when i edit this value to 987.89 and do ctrl+z all values goes off, and when i again do ctrl+z, i want 378.90 to be present

Comment: I have created one more input as number in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7agjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, to show how i am expecting

Comment: You can solve that issue by keeping the value as default. In the ngOnInit you can read the default value so keep that in a separate value and when you do ctrl+z and history is empty set your elements value to the default value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210643/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-billy-cottrell).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have accepted answer and added bounty to your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can select the input by simply using the `select` method on your element during the `focus` event in the `CurrencyInputDirective`.

```js
@HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
onFocus(value) {
    // on focus remove currency formatting
    this.el.value = value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '')
    this.el.select();
}
```

Now you will be able to select the whole option on clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. As for undoing all the changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, you can listen to the `keydown` event and remove the input accordingly. In your `CurrencyInputDirective`. Add a new `HostListener` to listen to the `keydown.control.z` event.

```js
@HostListener("keydown.control.z", ["$event.target.value"])
onUndo(value) {
    this.el.value = '';
}
```

#### [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-directive)

Comment: Thanks for response, it worked as i expected but when there is a value already in the input field, and i try to edit the value and do ctrlz, first time the value becomes empty, second time when i again do ctrlZ, it must give the value which was already present